# How to develop new component

Tags: joomla2.5

I am a new joomla programmer.i need to build new component for upload cv.my form fields are name, email and upload cv and submit button.i only need to build front end view form, filling the details and after click the submit button send the email.please help me create a component(joomla 2.5).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the stack-overflow. This is very basic question to ask you can easily search it in Google. But never mind you can check the given link for how to make component. see below.

[Developing a Model-View-Controller Component/2.5/Developing a Basic Component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Developing_a_Basic_Component)

You can use SWF upload to upload the files.see this

[Creating a file uploader in your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_file_uploader_in_your_component)

And for the email you can use it like this

[Sending email from extensions](http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions)

Comment: thanks Toretto..bt this is not a model part and i also upload the cv...please can u help coding structure??

Comment: So you need to upload files?

Comment: yes..i need to build controller and view file..please help me.bz i am not fammilier joomla coding..

Comment: I gave you the basic structure of how to upload a file and how to create a component.if you have any doubt after that please provide your code where you have problem?

Comment: ok.. have existing site.it is created by joomla. i need to create new component called "curriculum".it need to only front end.i want to create form including three field(name,email,upload cv) and submit button.click the submit button filling name,email and cv, then i need to send the email "Thank you,your cv is uploaded".....i don't fammilier joomla much...please Toretto, help me.

Comment: Have you made a basic component for front end?

Comment: @user1994980 See my updated answer this may help you.and please the read document properly this all I can suggest ,I can not give the detail functionality.Just prefer the link what I have given.